# With read committed snapshot isolation, what happens to the version after the commit

Tags: sql, sql-server, concurrency, isolation-level

With read committed snapshot isolation, what happens to the row version after the commit?

Is it permanently stored in the tempdp, or does it get deleted at some point?

And how to tell how much this will increase the tempdp size?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is stored permanently in `tempdb`, if it was, it would continue to grow until it filled available space, which of course is undesireable.

Rows are retained in the version store until the transaction that created them completes and any transactions that reference the modified data also complete. If it's a `select` that's referencing the version, it's removed once the statement completes. The version is flagged as ready and the actual cleanup handled by a separate process.

SQL Server maintains a cleanup thread to make sure it does not keep versioned rows around longer than needed which runs every minute and reclaims all reusable space from the version store.

If `tempdb` actually runs out of free space, SQL Server calls the cleanup function and will increase the size of the files, assuming it's configured for auto-grow; if `tempdb` files cannot grow, no more versions are generated and any query that needs to read that version will fail.

Numerous performance counters and meta data exist to monitor the RSCI usage of `tempdb`

`sys.dm_tran_version_store` contains information about all the rows currently in the version store. The `count` of rows here reflects the number of rows for all current RSCI transactions. A column called `transaction_sequence_number` contains an always-increasing sequence number for each new transaction.

You can get information about a connection currently running a transaction using

```
select  
    t.transaction_sequence_num,
    t.commit_sequence_num,
    t.is_snapshot,
    t.session_id,
    t.first_snapshot_sequence_num,
    t.max_version_chain_traversed,
    t.elapsed_time_seconds,
    s.host_name,
    s.login_name,
    s.transaction_isolation_level
from sys.dm_tran_active_snapshot_database_transactions t
    join sys.dm_exec_sessions s on t.session_id = s.session_id;
```

And you can get information about the usage and space consumed by `tempdb` using

```
select
    Db_Name(vsu.database_id) as DatabaseName,
    vsu.reserved_page_count, 
    vsu.reserved_space_kb, 
    tu.total_page_count as tempdb_pages, 
    vsu.reserved_page_count * 100. / tu.total_page_count as [Snapshot %],
    tu.allocated_extent_page_count * 100. / tu.total_page_count as [tempdb % used]
from sys.dm_tran_version_store_space_usage vsu
cross join tempdb.sys.dm_db_file_space_usage tu
where vsu.database_id = Db_Id(Db_Name());
```